# WPF Border Child visibility have no effect

Tags: c#, wpf, border, visibility, textblock

I need to hide a TextBlock that is child of a Border and is added to a Grid. The following code dynamically add the Border and the TextBlock to the Grid. Then if the Grid contain more than 5 children it hide the firsts children. It work correctly to hide the border but the TextBlock (the child of Border) remain visible.

Any idea where could be the problem? Thanks!

```
Border TextBorder = new Border();
TextBorder.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(_settings.TextColor);
TextBorder.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0,0,0,2);
TextBorder.Padding = new Thickness(0, 10, 0, 10);
RowDefinition rd = new RowDefinition();
rd.Height = GridLength.Auto;
myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rd);
TextBlock uc = new TextBlock();
uc.Text = "Test";
TextBorder.Child = uc;
Grid.SetRow(TextBorder, myGrid.RowDefinitions.Count -1);
myGrid.Children.Add(TextBorder);

if (myGrid.Children.Count > 5)
{
    Border border = (Border)myGrid.Children[myGrid.Children.Count - 6];
    border.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    border.Child.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

**Update**

The code work correctly. The problem was in OnRender event of the TextBlock that draw the text with some graphic effect. I though that if the control is invisible OnRender should not be raised but it seams that it is raised also when the control is invisible. I have not found a way to prevent OnRender to be raised, nor ClipToBound nor Invisible work. So I give up with this approach and I just check in OnRender if the TextBlock is in the visible area of the container.

Comment: Not really a clarification request, but anyway: why using code in WPF? Why not XAML?

Comment: border.Child.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
why not use 
    uc.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

Comment: @dymanoid I'v not understood your question. This code is in c# for a WPF application. I need to do this dynamically so I can't do it in the XAML code.

Comment: @DenisSchaf Because I need to hide the firsts TextBlocks not the current added

Comment: You can do everything dynamically in XAML, just use the styling and the templating mechanisms. But this is indeed off-topic for your question.

Answer (score -1):

first of all, I think what you do is something you should not do! 
But here is how you can do it (btw this assumes you only add Borders to your grid):

```
if (myGrid.Children.Count > 5)
{
   (myGrid.Children[myGrid.Children.Count - 6] as Border).Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

also i recommend to remove not to hide the child as it will otherwise stay in existance without any point

```
myGrid.Children.Remove(myGrid.Children[0]);
```

Comment: This is the same as: Border border = (Border)myGrid.Children[myGrid.Children.Count - 6];
    border.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden; The problem is that it make invisible only the Border and not the TextBlock child. Can you explain why you think it is somethigh I should not do? Do you have a better idea on how to achieve the seme result?

Comment: as you see in my edit remove them instead of just hiding them

Comment: i guess you re just starting to work with WPF so i guess the explanation for why this is not a good idea would exceed the scope of this question
But what you are basically making here is a listview so why not use a listview?

Comment: No, I work with WPF from long time. And no, I cannot use a listview because the full project is more complex and it use a ScrollView with animation effects and more stuff that is out of the scope of this question to explain. But the question here is just why the child of border don't become invisible.

Comment: And no, I can't remove or collapse it because I need to keep the empty space of the hidden TextBlock

Comment: instead of adding a border and add textblock to it make a customcontrol with the apperance you would like and add this custom control to your grid. By the way as a child always inherits from its parents your textbox should be hidden as well if not something else is wrong with what you do you can use the visual tree to track your issue down

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Unfortunately none of your suggestion apply to my needs but you are right on: "as a child always inherits from its parents your textbox should be hidden as well if not something else is wrong with what you do you can use the visual tree to track your issue down". Indeed the problem was something else ... the code in OnRender of the TextBlock.